# Could someone explain what this node.js code means please?

Tags: node.js

I'm doing learnyounode in terminal working through these exercises, I'm having a blast, but I just need a step by step explanation of what's going on in this code.

```
var fs = require('fs')

var filename = process.argv[2]
var buf = fs.readFileSync(filename)
var str = buf.toString();
var count = str.split('\n').length

console.log(count - 1)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read the file path from the supplied arguments, open the file and read it as a string. Count the number of lines in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var fs = require('fs')`

This is telling node to load the 'File System' package, named `fs`. It is used to manage file systems.

```
var filename = process.argv[2]
var buf = fs.readFileSync(filename)
var str = buf.toString()
```

the `filename` variable is reading in from the arguments at index 2 what looks to be a filename. Then, a buffer called `buf` is created to read in the data in this file. Then, `str` is created to cast that information as a `string`.

Finally, `var count = str.split('\n').length` takes this string and splits it by `\n`, or by line, into an array and takes the length of this array. This is now the number of lines.

`console.log(count - 1)` Simply outputs this number of lines to the console with a `- 1` to eliminate an extra newline at the end of the file, or some other extra data this author knows about.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! Could you tell me when I run this, why does it give me a different number every time? @Justin C

Comment: Well the only way that would be possible is if the `filename` variable is pointing to a different file. Try adding `console.log(filename)` after `var filename = process.argv[2]` to see what the filename is.

Comment: It comes up as "/var/folders/pf/0x9n5bts7y99kd1rm2c3ry9c0000gn/T/learnyounode_52597.tmp" @Justin C

Comment: It is possible that the file is being written to elsewhere. If you wanted to see what's in the file, try looping through your `str` variable with something like `for each(s in str) { console.log(s) }`

Answer (score 0):

Pulls in 'fs' module (file system functionality)

Opens a file using the third argument from the args list as a path

uses the fs import to read the contents of the file

splits the file contents into a line-by-line array and gets the array length (aka # of lines)

writes the array length minus 1, which is the last index of the array. If there is a header line, this could also be the number of content lines.

Answer (score 0):

This code will read a file and print number of lines

```
var fs = require('fs')
```

fs is a node module to do file operations. This line will create a `fs` variable that can access all exported functions in fs module. Its like an object to a class with access to all public functions. Its like a c `#include` statement or java `import` statement.

```
var filename = process.argv[2]
```

`argv` is a array containing list of arguments specified at the terminal/command-prompt. So this line would read the `filename` from terminal.

```
var buf = fs.readFileSync(filename)
```

this line will create a variable `buf` and save contents of file named `filename` into it. Contents will not be saved as string so the need to convert in next line.

```
var str = buf.toString();
```

`buf` has a method/function `toString()` prototyped to it by default. this method returns the variable converted to string, so `str` will have contents of original file as string.

```
var count = str.split('\n').length
```

`str` has split method prototyped by default. It take delimiter as the argument and returns an array of strings. So `str.split('\n')`  will return an array of separated lines(separated by '\n') and then `length` will be called on that array to return the its length.

you could divide it into two stages as follows

```
var lines = str.split('\n')
var count = lines.length
```

lastly `count` is reduced by 1 assuming a last blank line existed. `console.log` will log it into terminal/command prompt.

```
console.log(count - 1)
```